# Can Qlik Sense be uninstalled silently without the original exe?

Tags: installshield, uninstallation, silent

I'm installing Qlik Sense 3.2 as a prerequisite to another application. I'm using InstallShield 2016 to perform this task. Since InstallShield handles putting the files for prerequisites in some temp location I can't guarantee the location for the Qlik setup file in the event the user wants to uninstall later.

I know how to silently uninstall if the setup file is available.

Is there a way to silently uninstall Qlik without knowing the original Qlik_Sense_setup.exe file location?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Qlik, but if it is installed with its own MSI and you know the ProductCode for it you can uninstall it using msiexec.exe

> msiexec /x {ProductCode}

If you don't know the ProductCode you can open the cached MSI for it and find it there.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and let you know how it goes. Thanks. If it works I'll make sure to mark your answer